# wierd scatter plot points loop when plotting two features for regression

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, regression, scatter-plot

I am trying to implement linear regression on my weather data with maximum temperature and pressure as features.
I plotted them individually against time(time vs temperature and time vs pressure) and the plots seems fine however **when I plot temperature against pressure** (see the images attached) the plot is a closed loop of scatter point which worries me as I can't have a regression line in such a plot.
moreover, the Pearson correlation value for max-Temperature and Pressure is 0.732.

I was wondering if I should plot time vs temperature vs pressure 3d plot and apply regression on that.would that help solving my problem?
thanks.

**Temperature vs pressure:**
[image: temperature vs pressure]

**Temperature vs time:**
 
[image: temperature vs time]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HS23qzK3B9zVodYQOtJWZ10NeLQ6JTox

above is the link to data I'm using. It is in pickle format.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: I have posted the link to data I am using please check it out. @JamesPhillips

Comment: Thank you for the data link. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I plot time, temperature and pressure as a 3D scatterplot, it does not appear as if the data lies on a surface such that as 3D surface equation can be fitted to the data. Here is my 3D scatterplot:

[image: scatterplot]

Comment: Thank you for the effort but can you please explain what can I do with this data to predict future values. I mean it has a correlation of 0.7 which is quite nice there must be some way around. and I still don't get the point that when it is a time series data why does it make a loop of scatter points when temp and pressure is plotted against each other. please help me understand this.

Comment: If you look at the data as a 3D scatterplot and view the scatterplot from different angles, then what *appears* as a loop using only 2D projections is - as shown - actually curving around in 3D but does not make a 3D loop. True, when plotting only one data dimension against one other data dimension the correlation is not zero - that is, yes these data items are related. As for using this data set to predict future values, based on the 3D scatterplot alone it is my understanding that such a predictive mathematical model cannot be made using only this data.

Comment: Perhaps the data is seasonal, and you can compare seasons rather than have a single continuous time number? That's how I would approach this problem.

Comment: okay I get it now. thank you for pointing me in the right direction.